# Why is Access trying to append several rows instead of a single from a form?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a form in Access and added a query to insert a row into the database using the values in the form. When I run the query using a macro attached to a button the query appends the same number of rows that exist in the database instead of a single one. I can't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Access is not MySQL.

Comment: You mean that the number of rows in the DB double after each click on the button? Could you link a screenshot of the user interface? And could you copy-paste the query?

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks for the replies. It was because I had created a select query first from a Customer table and then changed it to be an append query. So when I checked the SQL for my append query the last line was "From Customer". When I removed this part the append query worked as directed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query pulls not the selected (current) record but all records of the source.

But don't use a query, use the RecordsetClone as shown here:

[Duplicate Record with New Primary Key (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213099/duplicate-record-with-new-primary-key-vba/39220032#39220032)