# Adding new records based on value in combobox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

What's the easiest way of adding new records to a table based on the number selected in a combobox?
I.E. I have selected the number 6 in a combobox and want it to add 6 records to a table, all with the same information.

Right now I'm using recAdd but by doing so I have to add code for each number that could be selected. If I choose 6 then I'm doing an if statement for 1 through 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function here: [Duplicate Record with New Primary Key (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213099/duplicate-record-with-new-primary-key-vba/39220032#39220032)

Wrap the add/update in a loop:

```
With rstInsert
  For i = 1 to CountOfNewRecords ' set to value from your combobox
    .AddNew
      For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
        With fld
          If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
            ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
          ElseIf .Name = "SomeFieldToPreset"
            rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = SomeValue
          ElseIf .Name = "SomeFieldToExclude"
            ' Leave blank
          Else
            ' All other fields.
            ' Copy field content.
            rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
          End If
        End With
      Next
    .Update
  Next
  ' Go to the new record and sync form.
  .MoveLast
  Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
  .Close
End With
```

Comment: Trying to figure out how to work that, I've played with it a bit but seems to be beyond my knowledge of VBA. My table is "UMD" and the field I'm wanting to populate is AFSC. The combobox name is cm038P3 and when a number is selected I want to add that number of fields into the table where the field AFSC will have that number number selected of rows where the AFSC is 038P3. So if 6 is selected it will add 6 rows where AFSC equals 038P3.

Comment: The table name is not used. Where to put the value from the combobox is already shown, and your value to insert will be `SomeValue", and the fieldname `"SomeFieldToPreset"` you can replace with `"AFSC"`.

Comment: I was able to figure it out about 20 minutes after I made the comment. I have 20 different combo boxes on a form, so I altered the code a bit to fit my needs. I cut a good chunk of it out, but thank you for putting me in the right direction!